# confusion about chebyshev theorem

Tags: probability-distributions

let us suppose that we have  following task :

Average  height  of those people who are  18 years old is  69.6 inch and standard deviation  is 1.4 inch,  question is what is the proportion (percentage of those people who fall between 68.2 and 71 inch (height) ?

i  know that if   distribution is normal then 68% will be  answer, but let us suppose that it is not normal distribution, then answer would be

$1-\frac{1}{k^2}$

that will fall  $k$ standard deviation  apart from mean, in our case  $k=1$, if we substitute $k=1$, then we will get  $0$, but how it could be? thanks in advance

Comment: Well it is a bound. $P(|X-1|<1)\color{red}{\geq} 0$. Isn´t the inequality true?

Comment: ok thanks in advance

Comment: You´re welcome.

Comment: i was thinking there there was something wrong,because at least 0 percentage does not make any sense

Comment: It makes sense, because the probability is greater than 0. But it is (maybe) not a good bound. It depends on how $X$ is distributed.